# janusgraph encounters `PermanentBackendException` while interacting with AWS opensearch version 7 and above

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, janusgraph, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

We are trying to run Janusgraph version `0.6.2` using AWS opensearch(elasticsearch) version 7.10 as the indexing backend. Things work fine with version 6.x but when we try to connect to version 7.x we encounter the following exception.

**org.janusgraph.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: method [PUT], host [https://vpc-xxxxxx.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com:443], URI [/_cluster/settings], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}**

Janusgraph version info:

```
86   [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer  - JanusGraph Version: 0.6.2
86   [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.server.JanusGraphServer  - TinkerPop Version: 3.5.3
```

More detailed stack trace is below:

```
3115 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Configuring index [search]
3387 [main] INFO  com.newforma.janusgraph.es.awsauth.AWSV4AuthHttpClientConfigCallback  - Initialized AWSV4AuthHttpClientConfigCallback for region us-east-2
3782 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager  - Graph [graph] configured at [/etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:80)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex
    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:79)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:527)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getIndexes(Backend.java:511)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.<init>(Backend.java:239)
    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:127)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.PermanentBackendException: method [PUT], host [https://vpc-xxxxxx.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com:443], URI [/_cluster/settings], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.setupMaxOpenScrollContextsIfNeeded(ElasticSearchIndex.java:445)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.<init>(ElasticSearchIndex.java:388)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [PUT], host [https://vpc-xxxxxx.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com:443], URI [/_cluster/settings], status line [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized]
{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:326)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:296)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:270)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.rest.RestElasticSearchClient.performRequest(RestElasticSearchClient.java:482)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.rest.RestElasticSearchClient.performRequest(RestElasticSearchClient.java:473)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.rest.RestElasticSearchClient.updateClusterSettings(RestElasticSearchClient.java:269)
    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.ElasticSearchIndex.setupMaxOpenScrollContextsIfNeeded(ElasticSearchIndex.java:443)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the stack trace it appears that janusgraph was trying to set a high value  for the elasticsearch property `max_open_scroll_context`. It is 500 by default.

AWS opensearch(elasticsearch) 7.x onwards doesn't let us set cluster properties.
Tried the following from kibana and I was able to get a similar response. This operation was supported in AWS managed elasticsearch 6.x version.

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
    "persistent" : {
        "search.max_open_scroll_context": 1024
    },
    "transient": {
        "search.max_open_scroll_context": 1024
    }
}

401 - Unauthorized
{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}
```

We can disable setting `max_open_scroll_context` property while janugraph starts by setting the property `index.[x].elasticsearch.setup-max-open-scroll-contexts` to `false`.

You can read more on this in configuration reference section on elasticsearch https://docs.janusgraph.org/configs/configuration-reference/#indexxelasticsearch